# Dynamic method call in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

How can I call a selector with its name in `NSString *` in objective c? I also need to call the selector only if the target will accept it. e.g.

```
+(void) callMethod: (NSString *) method onObject: (id) object
{
    // do some magic
}
```

When I call `callMethod: @"Foo" onObject: obj` if `obj` implements `Foo` then `[obj Foo]` should be called, if it doesn't implement it, nothing should happen.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(method);
if ([object respondsToSelector:selector]) {
    [object performSelector:selector];
}
```

Answer (score 6):

First, you use the [`NSSelectorFromString()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000055-BCIEICGB) method to convert the string into a method name, like so:

`SEL methodToCall = NSSelectorFromString(stringToConvertToMethod);`

Then, you check for the method on the receiver and call the method if it exists:

```
if ([receiver respondsToSelector:methodToCall]) {

  //  Method exists, call it.
  [receiver performSelector:methodToCall];

}
```

Just note that a potential downside is that you will not be able to pass in arguments. For passing an argument, you would call the NSObject method [`performSelector:withObject:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000052-BBCFACCF). For passing two arguments, [`performSelector:withObject:withObject:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000052-BBCGGCBE).